# When using django-allauth how do I get the Sites section in the admin page to show?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to learn it from *Django for Professionals* by William Vincent. After installing `django-allauth` and following the steps in the book, I managed to get the logging in and out the sign up functionality to work. However, when I go to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin`, I don't see a [Sites section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP2kd.png) This section is later used in the book to change the site being referred to (`example.com`) in the registration confirmation email.

I've searched for `django-allauth Site admin` in here and in the docs but I couldn't find anything about making the Sites section show.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/)

It should look probably something like -

admin.py

```
from django-allauth.models import Site  
from django.contrib import admin  

class DjangoAllAuthSiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
  pass

admin.site.register(Site, DjangoAllAuthSiteAdmin)
```

Comment: I tired it and I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-allauth'`. Same when I tried it with `django_allauth`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding `'django.contrib.sites'` to the `INSALLED_APPS` list within `settings.py`.